# How do I allow spaces when using Select2 tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using JQuery 1.10.2 and Select2 4.0.4 with the 'tags' option turned on.

```
$(this).select2({ 
   placeHolder: "Select One",
   allowClear: true, 
   tags: true, 
   tokenSeparators: [',']
});
```

What isn't working is if I try to type "New York" the space is ignored and a new tag is created as "NewYork".  It's like I didn't type it.  Is there a way to allow spaces in new 'tags' in Select2 options?

Comment: That's odd, I can't recreate it.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/oJipTmYKOcVTnRGa46tb?p=preview

This seems to work

Comment: @Roberrrt Thank you for looking at this.  It helps to know it works for someone else.  I'll keep digging.

Comment: Can you create a minimal, viable example?

Comment: Or simply host your own example in a codepen/plunkr?

Comment: @Roberrrt both good suggestions but my code is for a SAAS webapp that requires an account etc... and when I do a plunkr, it works for me there.

Comment: @Roberrrt I figured it out.  It was a conflict with two jquery plugins on that page.  The 'space' was being jacked by hotkeys and an old version of jstree.  Since jstree is only used in a small dialog on that page, I changes some of the jsTree code to make it play nice with others.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't propagate change event from the search field out of the component, I went throw the select2.min.js file and I have commented this validation:

```
n.trigger("keypress",e),e.which===i.SPACE&&e.stopPropagation()
```

or you can replace it with:

```
n.trigger("keypress",e),e.which===i.SPACE&&e.stopPropagation()
```

Comment: This is a really bad hack. Use `tokenSeparators` instead. OP used this correctly and found that there was some jQuery conflict that made it not work.